# Por que cuando intento enviar una String por correo en Python me sale el siguiente error:

Tags: python, smtp

simplemente estoy intentando leer un excel, lo almaceno en variables y luego creo una string con esas variables. Finalmente intento enviar esa string por correo a mi mismo(he quitado los datos de acceso en el código que copio a continuación) pero cuando ejecuto el código me da un error ***'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object'*** la hora de enviar el mail. No se que puede estar pasando.
A alguno se os ocurre algo?
Este es el código:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
 from email.mime.text import MIMEText
 import smtplib
 import pandas as pd
 import ast

columnas = ['Hotel', 'Nombre', 'Apellido 1', 'Apellido 2', 'Contraseña', 
'Departamento', 'Cuenta', 'Cargo', 'Tipo']
df = pd.read_excel('prueba.xlsx')
nombre = df[columnas[1]]
apellido1 = df[columnas[2]]
apellido2 = df[columnas[3]]
contraseña = df[columnas[4]]
mail = df[columnas[6]]

for i in [1]:
print(nombre[i] + " " + apellido1[i] + " " + apellido2[i])

message = "Hola ", nombre[i], " ", apellido1[i], " ", apellido2[
i], " . Su cuenta de Office 365 se ha creado con éxito. Sus datos para 
acceder son los siguientes: Usuario: ",
mail[i], " Contraseña: ", contraseña[i], " Saludos."
print(message)

server = smtplib.SMTP('ipservidordecorreo', 25)
server.login("test@gmail.com", "contraseña")
server.sendmail(
"test@gmail.com",
"test@gmail.com",
message)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 4):

Muy facil: no estás intentando enviar un *string*, sino **una tupla** de *string*.

```
message = "Hola ", nombre[i], " ", apellido1[i], " ", apellido2[i], " . Su cuenta de Office 365 se ha creado con éxito. Sus datos para acceder son los siguientes: Usuario: ", mail[i], " Contraseña: ", contraseña[i], " Saludos."
```

Con esa instrucción estás creando una tupla, no una cadena.

Puedes:

- O bien generar la cadena directamente (usando el operador correcto, que es `+`):

  ```
  message = "Hola " + nombre[i] + " " + ...
  ```
- O bien usar la función `join` para generar una cadena a partir de la tupla:

  ```
  message = ''.join( "Hola ", nombre[i], " ", apellido1[i], " ", ... )
  ```

Comment: Buenas, es correcto hago un print y se forma la cadena, pero cuando se intenta mandar por correo me sale lo siguiente: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @JabelÁlvarezAcosta Eso es otro problema distinto, no deberías hacer varias preguntas en una misma publicación. El mensaje dice que tu cadena tiene caracteres no correctos en la codificación Unicode. Como norma general, elimina las vocales acentuadas y las `ñ`.